# Can't access to amazon ec2 instance

Tags: php, ssh, amazon-ec2, filezilla

I can't access to amazon ec2 instance using ssh terminal:

```
ssh -i new.pem ubuntu@<public-ip>
```

It says connection closed by <public ip>

and FileZilla stopped working and I am getting this error:

> Error: Server unexpectedly closed network connection
>   Error:  Could not connect to server

This all happened after I changed the server's `/etc` folder's permissions to 775 to update the *php.ini* file.

What happened?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your instance may be hosed following the permission changes.

Take a look at this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive which describes a similar situation.

And a look at this potential resolution: https://serverfault.com/questions/234061/re-gaining-root-access-to-an-ec2-ebs-boot-image

Never had this happen to me so not personally used the recovery technique.

Good luck!