# Server unexpectedly closed network connection on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am getting the error of 'Server unexpectedly closed network connection' on Amazon ec2 Linux server. I tried to connect via putty and winscp too.

Till yesterday I was able to connect. Yesterday I just have given full permission to it's /etc/ directory and the subdirectories.

Now how to get resolve this issue. I have already raised a request to amazon support to set a default permission to /etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a very similar question:
[Can't access to amazon ec2 instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24734463/cant-access-to-amazon-ec2-instance)

From Matt Caton's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24739402):

> Take a look at this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive which describes a similar situation.
>
> And a look at this potential resolution: https://serverfault.com/questions/234061/re-gaining-root-access-to-an-ec2-ebs-boot-image