# Server unexpectedly closed network connection on AWS EC2

Tags: mysql, connection

It is a MySQL database server. When I login in AWS management console, it looks normal. But cannot connect to the server from any applications (PUTTY, MySQL clients, etc). Other than create a new instance, any ideas?

Comment: People here understand your urgency but can't help much without more information. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the server was running perfectly fine last night. then failed to connect from any machine, including other AWS server. No security group change. Login AWS console, it looks good as well.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400886/server-unexpectedly-closed-network-connection-on-amazon-ec2), with very similar title.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create new instance on aws. You can install phpmyadmin https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/ and just upload it using sftp and extract then access on the browser http://ec2/phpmyadmin_directory_name.

If you are trying to access ssh then you have to create pem key link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-key-pairs.html
then add the key to your putty. Thats it.